# Is chromes "appendChild" really that slow?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, google-chrome

I have a framework that generates the DOM of an app completely using `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild`. Now that the App gets bigger and bigger, I noticed that Chrome needs significantly longer to build the DOM as other Browsers.

So, I created the following performance test:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - now);
    },0);

}
```

The results of this test are very interesting:

- Chrome 16: 700+
- Firefox 9: 560
- IE 9: 210
- Opera 11.60: 51

Chrome took more than 14-times more time to complete than Opera.
And that´s not just a meaningless benchmark! I really can feel this difference in my app.

Is it normal that Chrome is that slow at DOM-operations?
Is there a way to speed it up?

Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` seems likely to throw off your timing.

Comment: You can insert the divs all at once instead one by one.

Comment: @Domenic you need setTimeout in this kind of benchmark so that the browser actually does work before you get the time

Comment: @Esailija not true, as shown in my perf test it's throwing you off: http://jsperf.com/appendchild-from-so Recall that `setTimeout` gets clamped to different values in different browsers.

Comment: If you had to create and add a tremendous number of DOM nodes, why wouldn't you use a document fragment (~450 ms on my machine) or append them to a parent outside of the document and then append that to the document (~60 ms)?  Presumably it's slow on all browsers because the renderer does lots of work.

Comment: Opera has some interesting optimizations that pop up here and there. It doesn't surprise me too much that it's the fastest.

Comment: @Domenic How does jsperf have any relevance? Anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/rZzYk/2/

Comment: @Esailija jsperf uses more accurate timing techniques. I duplicated the above test in JSPerf to show that it was the timing methodology that was flawed. Basically it's a matter of whether you trust JSPerf's timers vs. the OP's manually `new Date().getTime()` hacks.

Comment: @Domenic Yet it returns the correct result, which you can verify at least in chrome using the timeline tool. The rendering took 3.04s according to timeline, yet the first logged number is 600ms. That's because the browser only renders after logging of that time. If you defer the logging to be as soon as the thread is idle (I.E. `setTimeout( , 0)` you will get the time **after** rendering is done.

Comment: I had the same problem, though not inserting a large number of elements with JavaScript, but inserting (i.e. moving) a single element which already existed in the page. In my case, that single `appendChild()` operation is taking 15s on a top-of-the-line computer with Chrome, while taking a negligible time on Firefox.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the workarounds I've seen on this page worked (doing the `appendChild()` in a fragment created with `document.createDocumentFragment()` and then using `appendChild()` to insert that fragment, or hiding the whole page with `display: none` while the insertion is done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is normal... .

The same goes for HTML Objects manipulation (width & height & opacity), especially if you're using CSS3.

I programmed a Slideshow (not using jQuery, i hate it) which is working smoothly... in FF, IE, Opera, Safari,... but not Chomre. In Chrome it is unbelievable slow (only in newer Chrome Versions, in old like v12 it was faster).

Answer (score 5):

***Update 2***

Here's a hackish sort of solution, that may be worth a little browser detection. It brings the performance in my testing down to less than <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10</sub> of what it was.

You can `display='none'` the container before the appends, then show it again after. You may get a little bit of a flash, but that's probably better than a long delay.

```
window.onload = function(){

    var content = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));

       // cache it in case it is already set
    var disp = document.body.style.display;

    document.body.style.display = 'none';

    var now = new Date().getTime();

    for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
          .appendChild(document.createTextNode( content ));
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - now);
        document.body.style.display = disp || ''; // restore it
    },0);
};
```

This is the sort of performance increase that I would have expected from the `documentFragment`.

---

***Update***

After running a [modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/rZzYk/3/) of [@Esailija's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) jsFiddle test to include the *documentFragment*, it doesn't seem to make any difference in Chrome (or Opera for that matter), so it appears as though Chrome is simply slower.

---

> *"Is there a way to speed it up?"*

I'm guessing that you'll get better performance if you use a `documentFragment`, and then append to the DOM with a single `.appendChild`.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();

      // create a documentFragment
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        frag.appendChild(Div());  // append to the documentFragment
    }

      // append the documentFragment (which is emptied)
    document.body.appendChild(frag);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - now);
    },0);

    function Div(){
        var This = document.createElement("div");
        return This;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a documentFragment would speed it up tremendously, or any container that isn't yet part of the DOM. I would guess Opera doing this "behind the scenes", which isn't always the expected behavior.

Comment: Your update is right, using your code does not really speed it up. There is a difference, but only about 50ms... I still think there should be a solution to this... :S

Comment: @VanCoding: Considering that most of the time is coming from the page redraw, I don't know if you'll really be able to change that. If you're hoping to avoid the browser appearing frozen, you could break up the task into smaller asynchronous chunks to allow the user to still interact with the page. Aside from that, I don't know what you could do to improve Chrome's redraw performance. That's pretty well under the hood.

Comment: True. I´ll report this as a bug to the chrome dev team.

Comment: @VanCoding: I have sort of a hackish solution for you. If you do `document.body.style.display = 'none';` before the loop, then in the `setTimeout` do `...display = ''`, the performance it seems to remove the redraw performance entirely. I'll update.

Comment: Well we've doing lots of writes to a DIV containing log-data.  Data related to packets coming in from WebSockets and each is logged. Logging to a DIV whose visibility is not set to None results in a total freeze on Chrome. Logging to a DIV whose visibility IS set to none does not seem to cause ANY performance issues. So we just show the log when users 'opens'.

Answer (score 0):

Your test appears flawed. If you do a pure `appendChild` test, Chrome comes out way ahead:

http://jsperf.com/appendchild-from-so

Comment: benchmarking only the call of appendChild is not enough! It´s true that the call itself is really fast, but after JS goes to idle, chrome still has a lot to do before he can start the next tick. In all other browsers, that seems to be different. However: I wanted to benchmark the whole process, including all processing time.